# How can we repeat a pattern of elements using for loop and input info on array in jsx by also including CSS classes and tags?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
          <div>
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> A </label>
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> B </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> C </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> D </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> E </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> F </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> G </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> H </label> 
            <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon"/> I </label> 
          </div>
```

I am having trouble inputting class names, tags and texts at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `map`, `for loop` or `forEach loop`.

```
data= ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Javascript', 'React', 'Java', 'Android', 'Python', 'PHP', 'MySQL']
```

Using Map,

```
<div>
  {data.map((val) => (
    <label className="tag"><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon">{val}</label >
  ))}
</div>
```

Using for loop and forEach is also quite similar just wrap your code within `{ }`. Still you can see the documentation from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You can loop like this one:

```
<div>
    {
        ['A','B','C','D','E','F'].map(x=> {
            return <label className='tag'><BsFillCheckCircleFill className="tag-icon" />{x}</label>
        })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. Its giving 2 pages filled with errors.

Comment: Can you share what's errors are?

Comment: The messages are too long to share here. Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot link

Comment: Add the errors to the question

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/yjWNNu4HC2Rn.png ERRORS SCREENSHOT

Comment: @Greg it means that items of your array are objects, not strings. Please edit the question t show your actual setup

Comment: @Greg: use `{x}`, not `{{x}}`. And make sure your array list string of array